# not able to mount burned ISO9660 file-system before ejecting and re-inserting the media

Tags: debian, data-cd

After burning an *ISO9660* file-system(`wodim -v dev='/dev/scd0' -sao ubcd521.iso`) to a CD, I always need to first eject the CD and then re-inserted it in order to be able to mount the created CD:

```
root@T42:~# file -s /dev/sr0 
/dev/sr0: data
root@T42:~# mount -t iso9660 /dev/sr0 /media/
mount: block device /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

root@T42:~# eject
root@T42:~# #re-inserted CD tray
root@T42:~# file -s /dev/sr0 
/dev/sr0: ISO 9660 CD-ROM filesystem data 'UBCD521                        ' (bootable)
root@T42:~# mount | grep cd
/dev/sr0 on /media/cdrom0 type iso9660 (ro,noexec,nosuid,nodev,user=usr)
root@T42:~#
```

I'm just wondering what causes this?

Comment: Something seems to *auto-mount* the image for you... as *you did not actually mount it* after you re-insert the tray... Btw, maybe `mount -o loop /path/of/ubcd521.iso /mnt` saves you the burning by just mounting the ISO file

Comment: Maybe some `udev` event has to be triggered, you could try to do this with [`udevadm`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/udevadm)

Comment: If no other OS supports reading CDs without ejecting them first either, it's probably a limitation by hardware. When you put a CD into a drive, before you can access it the drive itself reads the properties of the media (such as data size, number of tracks, etc). If there's no way to reset that without ejecting (because you changed things after re-writing a CDRW) then that's what you have to do. It's silly but there you are...